# Python Function to replace json patterns from a file and compare with the API Results

Tags: json, python-2.7

I need to create a function in python that helps me read a JSON file and compare the results to the JSON received from an API. 
The problem is that some parameters are always different, like the “Id” or “createdAt” and I want to use Json Paths inside the file to be replaced by the API response and then compare the results with those informations. 
Does anyone can help me with it? I have a simple example here, but in some cases I have JSON with 100+  itens and using the Json Path expressions would be a lot easier.

What i receive from API:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "createdAt": "2019-11-28 15:18:32+0000",
            "name": "name1",
            "id": 1,
            "enabled": true,
            "updatedAt": "2019-11-28 15:18:32+0000"
        },
        {
            "createdAt": "2019-11-28 15:18:32+0000",
            "name": "name2",
            "id": 2,
            "enabled": true,
            "updatedAt": "2019-11-28 15:18:32+0000"
        }, 
    ]
}
```

What i wanna send in a json file to compare the results:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "createdAt": "$..roles[0].createdAt",
            "name": "name1",
            "id": 1,
            "enabled": true,
            "updatedAt": "$..roles[0].updatedAt"
        },
        {
            "createdAt": "$..roles[1].createdAt",
            "name": "name2",
            "id": 2,
            "enabled": true,
            "updatedAt": "$..roles[1].updatedAt"
        }, 
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry @ScottHunter, i have actually the json diff function already, but it does not read the json paths as "variables", so my function does nothing.

```
 def compare(location1, location2):
  json1 = getContent(location1)
  json2 = getContent(location2)
  diff1 = Diff(json1, json2, True).difference
  diff2 = Diff(json2, json1, False).difference
  diffs = []
  for type, message in diff1:
    newType = 'THIS ELEMENT HAS NOT THE SAME VALUE'
    if type == PATH:
      newType = 'REMOVED'
    diffs.append({'type': newType, 'message': message})
  for type, message in diff2:
    diffs.append({'type': 'ADDED', 'message': message})
  return diffs
```